# Effective way of rendering a lot of quads (LibGDX/OpenGL ES)

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, render

I want to ask you what is the most effective or atleast sufficient way to render a lot of quads. I want to render a lot of quads (atleast 150x150) aligned in grid. The quads will not have any textures, just solid background (green,black) but colors can be changed during a runtime. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Could you give some more details about how you will use these quads? Will they ever move (as a grid or as single objects)?

Comment: They will not move, position will be static, only the color will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always abstract it to some sort of editable mesh object which can keep a list of indexes for the points to be drawn, a list of vertices which are drawn in order of the indexes, and then the colour for each vertex. You can then add to this dynamically at run time, and then prepare the mesh everytime you change it, which will bind everything to a VBO, and then you can simply draw it. Everything else is just implementation detail, but if you have a decent knowledge of OpenGL VAO's and VBO's should be fairly trivial. But otherwise I can help with this if you need.

Update(As there isn't enough space in the comment):

If I recall correctly, drawElements is the way to go. Don't draw each object separately, if you do that, you might as well use immediate mode. glDrawElements basically batches all of the information to your graphics card at once where it is all done as much in parallel as possible. If you draw one thing at a time, you won't be taking full advantage of the power of the GPU.

After your comment, this is where you need to make some design decisions based on what you need to do. So you want to translate individual meshes, and then eventually we want to build up a giant buffer which allows us to draw everything at once. So the first step would be to determine how much of the mesh will be moving.

Lets say we have 2 blocks that move, but the rest are stationary, we can create a separate editable mesh from these 2 blocks, and create our giant mesh from the remaining blocks. Another thing to check would be, how often is our mesh going to move? If it moves maybe once every minute or so, I would say its not such a big issue to recreate the entire mesh and bind the data again(assuming the mesh isn't ridiculously large, in which case you can create submeshes and only update those which need updating).

On the point in my previous paragraph, what are you going to be using the translated vertices for? If you are only using it for visual purposes, you can get away with creating a model matrix for your transforms for each sub-mesh that needs to be translated. However if you are going to be using it for things like collision detection you will need to store this information so that it can be used elsewhere. However you can still get away with just using the transform matrix instead of updating the VBO.

Hope this helps in some way! :)

Comment: So should i create some object which holds vertices, color and indices, and then i create one big buffer which will contain vertices, colors etc fro m all my objects? or draw each object separately? I also want to ask you what is more effective? glDrawElements or glDrawArrays? for this purpose of course. And what if i create only one array of vertices and my object will have Vec position, then if I do translation for each object is it waste of performance? (sorry for bad english)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's very helpful :) SO Basically I will create object representating quad with pos,color,indices then create one big VBO with pos + colors of all objects + one big array with all indices and draw it in one batch, am I right? Isn't here some more efficient? Because all objects will be same size, only position and color can be different and position will be set only once (at initialization) and then object can change only color. I read something about instancing but then I found that it probably is not available for OpenGL ES < 3. Thanks for your advice & tips.

Comment: Yeah, so with the VBO everything will be drawn in one batch, that is the advantage of using a VBO for binding all of your vertex data. It basically hands everything over to the GPU and it draws it all in one batch. On the note of display lists, you could look at that yes, but I'm not familiar with ES and if the API is the same as the normal API. But yes, you've got the idea. Let me know if you get it working, and maybe post a link to some screenshots or something :)

Comment: Thanks Daniel :) I created some class representing Quad (holds vertices, indices), then create Libgdx's object called Mesh, set Vertex attrib, create one big array with all vertices, indices and also bind it to Mesh, then render that mesh. Speed was quite good so I think it will be sufficient for my purposes. One more thanks for your willingness :)

Comment: But what if I want to change color of any specific Quad? Will I have to recreate whole buffer?

Comment: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices this page provides some decent info on best practices. But basically it boils down to how your data should be organized. I'm assuming all the squares will be changing colour, so you can bind the colour to your Buffer on your VBO as well, but you can bind it to a separate pointer, this means if you want to update colours on your mesh(or any other value for that matter) you can only update that attribute specifically.

Comment: Yea, I Will accept, but I don't have enough reputation for VOTE-UP :( :D